# How to execute a file with multiple queries in Godror?

Tags: oracle, go

I would like to execute an sql-file with the godror Oracle driver for Go. My problem is that godror does not accept more than 1 query in the file. Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

```
db2, _ := sql.Open("godror", databaseURL)

c, ioErr := ioutil.ReadFile(sqlFile)

_, err := db2.Exec(string(c))   

defer db2.Close()
```

With this code this query works:

```
create TABLE books3 (title VARCHAR2(100))
```

But this doesn't:

```
create TABLE books3 (title VARCHAR2(100));
create TABLE books4 (title VARCHAR2(100));
create TABLE books6 (title VARCHAR2(100));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your own file parser to extract the statements from the file, and execute them one at a time. It's easier if you use a slightly stricter syntax than SQL*Plus files can have, e.g. if you always use `/` as the terminator for both SQL & PL/SQL, and you make sure the file doesn't contain SQL*Plus statements (like COLUMN).  One related parser is in Python at https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/7.3/samples/SampleEnv.py#L124-L157

A better way is probably to store the strings in your Go code.